# Does server.closeAllConnections also close idle connections?

Tags: node.js, http, server, https, connection

From the Node.js docs:

> `server.closeAllConnections()` (added in: `v18.2.0`)
>
> - Closes all connections connected to this server.
>
> `server.closeIdleConnections()` (added in: `v18.2.0`)
>
> - Closes all connections connected to this server which are not sending a request or waiting for a response.

If I want to ensure all connections are closed, is it safer to call the two?

```js
server.closeIdleConnections()
server.closeAllConnections()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `server.closeAllConnections()` will close all connections, including idle connections.

- The `closeAllConnections()` function loops over the result of `this[kConnections].all()`.
- The corresponding underlying `ConnectionsList::All()` C++ function [loops over `list->all_connections_`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3838b579e44bf0c2db43171c3ce0da51eb6b05d5/src/node_http_parser.cc#L1076-L1079), just [as `ConnectionsList::Idle()`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3838b579e44bf0c2db43171c3ce0da51eb6b05d5/src/node_http_parser.cc#L1093-L1098), but without any kind of filtering.

So no, `closeIdleConnections()` is not needed.

**Reference:**

- JS code: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3838b579e44bf0c2db43171c3ce0da51eb6b05d5/lib/_http_server.js#L570-L596
- C++ code: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3838b579e44bf0c2db43171c3ce0da51eb6b05d5/src/node_http_parser.cc#L1068-L1102